# Jasper Report With Dynamic Params

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a Report that I created in *Jaspersoft Studio* that has a parameter as part of the main dataset query:

```sql
select *
from subjects as s
join juror_subjects as js on js.resources_id = s.resources_id
join resources as r on r.id = s.resources_id
join matters as m on m.id = r.matters_id
where r.id = $P{subjects_id}
```

when I preview this in *Jaspersoft Studio*, it prompts for the subjects_id, and once I enter it, the report runs successfully.

Also, when I run it on *JasperReports Server*, it prompts for the subjects_id, and once I enter it, the report runs correctly.

However, when I request it from our API (which is the ultimate implementation we are aiming for), it returns a blank page.

API code:

```
public function main(){        

    $inputControls = array(
        'subjects_id' => 95488
    );

    $report = $this->c->reportService()->runReport('/reports/JurorReport', 'pdf', null, null, $inputControls);
    header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
    echo $report;
    die;
}
```

This API code is just for test purposes right now.

Can anyone help me understand why I am unable to request reports with $P parameters in the dataset query?  I have confirmed that if I remove the parameters, the report runs correctly.

Comment: The class of $P{subjects_id} is java.lang.Integer? or java.lang.Long?

Comment: I was previously set to java.lang.Integer.  Upon reading your comment, I tried java.lang.Long as well, but had the same results.  Which type should it be set as?

Comment: it should correspond to database type, but as long as its not was a java.lang.String, both should work.